Suing people vs. a company
I work for a small trucking company. Have for almost 3 years. We haul out of the same places all week long. Sometimes change it up, but can guarantee to see the places at least twice a week.
The one facility we hauled out of had some bad office ladies. (Particularly 1) if you got on her bad side she believed she was superior and needed to show you who's in control of your loads.
Well I'm a smart butt with my words and I will state facts to your face before talking behind your back. So one day I was held up for an hour while 6 of the unloaders were hiding in the back of the facility. I did not lose my cool I said okay, whatever and asked if I get an ice cream cone or something for my wait. We all laughed and I left. The next morning I went in 35 minutes early from my pick up time and was told I need to wait for a door, there were only 3 trucks in the 21 doors available. I say "oh, so my over an hour wait yesterday because first shift doesn't want to do their job means I get to wait today? The office lady shut the window before I finished. I push open the big metal door, and let it slam behind me (as all drivers do) while outside I yell "F@#$" and get in my truck. Well I come in at 6:57am and say "I know I'm a few minutes early but was wondering if I could get a door now?" Trying to make light of it all. And the office lady giggled a bit.
(Side note, there are no cameras there)
Well I'm on my way to get my second load for the day and 1 hour before I get there my company calls and said I am banned from the facility because I was slamming doors and kicking things. I have not seen the email, nor has my company offered to show it to me.
In law, can I sue anyone in this for anything??
What this banishment has done is hurt my income drastically. My company has purposely given me bad load assignments probably hoping I'd quit.
Any help would be great, I'll answer any questions. Thank you all!

It’s their property, if they don’t want you there, you can’t come in
As long as it isn’t for a prohibited reason, you have no recourse. Banning you for slamming doors and swearing is fine.

Okay, but the door slams all the time. I did not slam a door. I was outside when I cussed. Then they also said it was a numerous offense. When infant that was the only time.

You get to decide who can come on your property; so do they.
